# Feed an intermediate digest to a sha-1 function?

Tags: sha1

I need to compute a hash of a text that is in two pieces, held by two different parties, who should not have access to each others' texts.

Since SHA-1 is incremental I have heard that this should be possible but cannot find any answers with Google of any libraries that implement this.

I'd like the first party to SHA-1 hash its part of the text, and then feed the hash (digest) to the 2nd party, and they will continue with hashing, and compute the total digest of the combined texts. If this is possible, does anyone know of any library that takes a text and a previous hash as input arguments? Preferably in javascript or python but I'm actually happy to accept any language.

Update: I am looking at the source code of the [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/js/sha1.js) (javascript) implementation of SHA-1, and see this code in the update method:

```
// initialize hash value for this chunk
a = s.h0;
b = s.h1;
c = s.h2;
d = s.h3;
e = s.h4;
```

And at the end of that method:

```
s.h0 = (s.h0 + a) | 0;
s.h1 = (s.h1 + b) | 0;
s.h2 = (s.h2 + c) | 0;
s.h3 = (s.h3 + d) | 0;
s.h4 = (s.h4 + e) | 0;
```

So it seems that by carrying these values + any remaining data in the input buffer over, one should be able to re-create the state of the SHA-1 object at party number 2. So a bit of the buffer will leak over but I think that should be fine. Will investigate further to see if this works.

Comment: You're on the right track. Some background: Sha1 uses the [Merkle–Damgård construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) and processes the input in blocks of 512bits. If possible, I would align the separate parts to these block boundaries so you do not have to transmit partial blocks. Note that the library buffers more data than necessary for Sha1, so you should take care not to transmit more than the partial block (at most 63bytes).

Comment: Thanks @Perseids, I will try to adapt forge so that I can export these parameters and recreate a hash of the entire text in a separate session.